Cannot access database from other page. .Net Maui App
I am having some difficulties with .net Maui. I have started working on an incremental reader app and  decided that i would use an EFC inMemory database. I downloaded all the nugets, created the DbContext. Added two items to the database. Everything seems to be working. Then I go try and access the database from another page (SelectArticleViewPage) in the app. And it says its null. I go back to the page where it works (ArticleViewPage) and there are two items in the database. I cannot understand why it is like this. Ive used InMemory before for console apps, and never had this issue.
I tried googling this issue. Have not found any results. I did find that InMemory is used mainly fo testing cause it works only once per process? So my train of thought is that opening a new page is considered a new process so the database will be empty for that process. Will create a mssql database when i get back from work to see if the problem persists. This is more of a theoretical question, i dont expect any concrete solutions.
DbContext:
using IncrementalReader.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IncrementalReader.Data
{
    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Item> ArticleItems { get; set; }

        public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDatabase");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(
                i => i.ChildItems).WithOne(i => i.Parent).HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentId);
            
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(
            //    i => i.ChildItemFlashCard).WithOne(i => i.Parent).HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentId);
        }
    }
}

MainPage:
using IncrementalReader.Data;
using IncrementalReader.MVVM.ViewModel;
using IncrementalReader.MVVM.Views;

namespace IncrementalReader
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        TestDbContext _testDbContext;
        public MainPage(TestDbContext testDbContext)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _testDbContext = testDbContext;


            foreach(var item in _testDbContext.ArticleItems.ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            
        }
        private void NewArticleButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlePage(_testDbContext));
        }
        private void LoadArticleButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SelectArticleViewPage(_testDbContext));
        }

        
    }

}

Article Page (where the db works):
public partial class ArticlePage : TabbedPage
{
    
    public ArticlePage(TestDbContext testDbContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = new ArticlePageViewModel(testDbContext).GetById(2);
    }

    

    
}



using IncrementalReader.Data;
using IncrementalReader.Models;
using IncrementalReader.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IncrementalReader.MVVM.ViewModel
{

    public class ArticlePageViewModel

    {

        private readonly TestDbContext _testDbContext;
        private readonly List<Item> itemList;
        public ArticlePageViewModel(TestDbContext testDbContext)
        {          
            _testDbContext = testDbContext;
            itemList = _testDbContext.ArticleItems.ToList();
            if (!itemList.Any())
            {
                _testDbContext.ArticleItems.Add(
                    new Item { HeaderText = "Lorem Ipsum", BodyText = "Lorem Ipsum cos tam cos tam"
                    }
                );
                _testDbContext.ArticleItems.Add(
                    new Item { HeaderText = "Lorem Ipsum", BodyText = "Lorem Ipsum cos tam drugi tekst"
                    }
                );
                _testDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            
        }

        

        public Item GetById(int id)
        {
            Item retrievedItem = _testDbContext.ArticleItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
            
            return retrievedItem;
        }
    }
}

SelectArticleViewPage:
using IncrementalReader.Data;
using IncrementalReader.MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace IncrementalReader.MVVM.Views;

public partial class SelectArticleViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public SelectArticleViewPage(TestDbContext _testDbContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new SelectArticleViewModel(_testDbContext);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}



using IncrementalReader.Data;
using IncrementalReader.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IncrementalReader.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class SelectArticleViewModel
    {
        public TestDbContext testDbContext;
        public SelectArticleViewModel(TestDbContext _testDbContext)
        {
            testDbContext = _testDbContext;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItems()
        {
            return testDbContext.ArticleItems.ToList();
        }
    }
}


Have you considered creating a singleton view model?

Those are not view models. You named the files "ViewModel" but they do not behave like such. Your logic is split between pages and viewmodels anyway. You are not using the dependency injection. You are calling db methods in the constructor of the pages.

I split the logic casue im trying to use the MVVM pattern, where the view model is the page that handles all backend business logic
, while the view page only has miniml contact with it via data bindings and implements commands and events for the front end XAML page. I am probably implementing it wrong.... And that is correct i didnt use DI... i probably should implement it....

Have you tried implementing BindingContext = new ArticlePageViewModel(testDbContext).GetById(2); in the ViewModel?
